# Is there any problem with my flex-grow animation not working properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created div with flex only one active in at a time. It seems working well in body with 1200px, but less than 1200px its start flickering due to inside hide/show (class content) on transition.

If I will not change content class display none from flex it is working well; but I need to switch display flex.

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/dhoni/pen/vPvKNx) and snippet below:

```js
$('.top div').click(function(){
  $('.top div').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
}
.top .item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 180px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.top .item .flexo-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.top .item .flexo-box img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
}
.top .item .view-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.top > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.top .active {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-basis: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .active-tab {
  height: 50px;
}
.content .active-tab p, .content .archive-tab p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}
.content .active-tab p.active, .content .archive-tab p.active {
  background: blue;
}
.content .active-tab p.active + span, .content .archive-tab p.active + span {
  background: blue;
}
.content .active-tab span, .content .archive-tab span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.item.active .flexo-box:hover .view-btn {
  opacity: 1;
}
.item.active .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.item > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      <span class="view-btn">
      <a href="/jobs/12526/proof_documents/19776" class="btn btn-secondary proof__order__link ">
          View File
      </a>
  </span>
    </div>
      <div class='content'>
        <div class="active-tab">
        <p>dfgsfgsfg<p>
        
        <p class="active">012620_11254_LEN_78441.pdf</p>
        <span>fsdfgfs0<span>
        <div class="archive-tab">
          <h3>Archived file</h3>
          <p>012620_87896_LEN_11548.pdf</p>
          <span> archived dfgfd4<span>
           <p>012620_16975_LEN_98761.pdf<p>
           <span>archived sdfgsfg</span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
          </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" onerror="this.src = 'http://10.0.0.73:3000/assets/placeholder-6c8626f646674836d73093c5cd6377a4b8a05f672e0f14147692482e930d9bba.jpg'">
    </div>
      <div class='content'>
        hello
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='item active'>
    <div class='flexo-box'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        hello
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div  class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'></div>
      <div class='content'>
        hello
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div  class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" onerror="this.src = 'http://10.0.0.73:3000/assets/placeholder-6c8626f646674836d73093c5cd6377a4b8a05f672e0f14147692482e930d9bba.jpg'">
    </div>
      <div class='content'>

        
        <div class="active-tab">
        <p>current file<p>
        
        <p class="active">012620_11254_LEN_78441.pdf</p>
        <span>wertrwet 190314 1250<span>
        <div class="archive-tab">
          <h3>Archived file</h3>
          <p>012620_87896_LEN_11548.pdf</p>
          <span> wert ertrwet4<span>
           <p>012620_16975_LEN_98761.pdf<p>
           <span> 190309 1ertret152</span>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
        
        
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: codepen link https://codepen.io/dhoni/pen/vPvKNx

Comment: Any reason for down vote?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @selva always add a *snippet* to the question, even though you have external links - see the edited question... pls follow guidelines as you are now aware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `display` property can't be animated - so remove `display: none` from `content` and add these:

```
.item>.content { 
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now the `content` will be zero-width and the `flexo-box` will occupy all space. Note the use of `min-width: 0` - this allows the *flex item* to *shrink* beyond its content (default `min-width` of a *flex item* is `auto`).

Now you can add `min-width: 0` to the `item` too for a smoother animation - see demo below:

```js
$('.top div').click(function() {
  $('.top div').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
}

.top .item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 180px;
  transition: all .5s;
  min-width: 0; /* added */
}

.top .item .flexo-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.top .item .flexo-box img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.top .item .view-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.top>div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.top .active {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-basis: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content {
  /*display: none;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.content .active-tab {
  height: 50px;
}

.content .active-tab p,
.content .archive-tab p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
}

.content .active-tab p.active,
.content .archive-tab p.active {
  background: blue;
}

.content .active-tab p.active+span,
.content .archive-tab p.active+span {
  background: blue;
}

.content .active-tab span,
.content .archive-tab span {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.item.active .flexo-box:hover .view-btn {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item.active .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.item>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.item>.content { /* added */
  min-width: 0; /* allow it to go to zero */
  flex: 0; /* reduce the width */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide oveflow */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
      <span class="view-btn">
      <a href="/jobs/12526/proof_documents/19776" class="btn btn-secondary proof__order__link ">
          View File
      </a>
  </span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class="active-tab">
        <p>dfgsfgsfg</p>
        <p class="active">012620_11254_LEN_78441.pdf</p>
        <span>fsdfgfs0</span>
        <div class="archive-tab">
          <h3>Archived file</h3>
          <p>012620_87896_LEN_11548.pdf</p>
          <span> archived dfgfd4</span>
          <p>012620_16975_LEN_98761.pdf</p>
          <span>archived sdfgsfg</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" onerror="this.src = 'http://10.0.0.73:3000/assets/placeholder-6c8626f646674836d73093c5cd6377a4b8a05f672e0f14147692482e930d9bba.jpg'">
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      hello
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='item active'>
    <div class='flexo-box'></div>
    <div class='content'>
      hello
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'></div>
    <div class='content'>
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class='flexo-box'>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" onerror="this.src = 'http://10.0.0.73:3000/assets/placeholder-6c8626f646674836d73093c5cd6377a4b8a05f672e0f14147692482e930d9bba.jpg'">
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class="active-tab">
        <p>current file</p>
        <p class="active">012620_11254_LEN_78441.pdf</p>
        <span>wertrwet 190314 1250</span>
        <div class="archive-tab">
          <h3>Archived file</h3>
          <p>012620_87896_LEN_11548.pdf</p>
          <span> wert ertrwet4</span>
          <p>012620_16975_LEN_98761.pdf</p>
          <span> 190309 1ertret152</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```